# How can I push my local git project to shared hosting

Tags: git, push, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a git repo on my local PC and that is synced with bitbucket. I purchased shared hosting form Namecheap and trying to push my local repo to Namecheap hosting. I followed

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9586/89/how-to-deal-with-git-on-our-shared-servers

this link. But the problem is when I push my local repo to Namecheap host, it sends the data but no files are changed actually.

How can I add shared hosting as remote and push my local files frequently?

Comment: _"send the data but no files are change actually"_ what do you mean? Do you understand what a remote is?

Comment: I know what a remote is, brother, when i push, all the files are successfully transmitted to remote host, but changes are not visible

Comment: What kind of remote is it? A bare repo?

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes it is bare repo

Comment: And you're using that to serve the files?

Comment: remote repo is bare, i want to push my local repo to bare repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169094/discussion-between-aziz-and-evolutionxbox).